# How to Access User Email and Password from MySql PhpMyadmin Local host

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I can't access User email and password from phpmyAdmin local host Database
this is my code for Login button

```
 private void jButton2LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    Connection con=myConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {

      //Selecting UserName and Password From DataBase 


      ps =con.prepareStatement("SELECT `userName`,` Password` FROM           
        `user` WHERE `userName` = ? AND `password`= ? ");

       ps.setString(1, jTextFieldUserName.getText());

       ps.setString(2,String.valueOf( jPasswordField1.getPassword()));

        rs=ps.executeQuery();

         if(rs.next()){

          MyContactForm mcf=new MyContactForm();
            mcf.setVisible(true);

             mcf.pack();
            mcf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mcf.jLabel2UserName.setText(rs.getString(1));

            this.dispose();
       }else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Error");
       }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(" Error");
        Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

> Error
>   Dec 27, 2018 12:54:00 PM Front.LoginForm jButton2LoginActionPerformed
>
> SEVERE: null
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '
>
> Password' in 'field list'

Comment: You have an extra space before `Password` in your query.

Comment: i have remove extra space now it Work .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra space before Password in query.